# SQL Sever - Weird DateDiff Behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have the following simple query

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -32, '2020-02-29')-32, -1)
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -31, '2020-02-29')-31, -1)
```

I would expect the output for each line would be different due to the differing number of months in -31 and -32.

Both of these lines return 2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 and I have absolutely no idea why!

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: This is explained in the documentation.  End of months are handled specially.

Comment: select DATEDIFF(MONTH, -32, '2020-02-29') returns 1443
select DATEDIFF(MONTH, -31, '2020-02-29') returns 1442

I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: `DATEDIFF(MONTH, -32, '20200229')-32 = DATEDIFF(MONTH, -31, '20200229')-31 = 1443 - 32 = 1442-31 = 1411` @Alec ... No matter what way you look at the value `1411` adding that many months to the date `1899-12-31` will always result in the date `2017-07-31`.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What is `DATEDIFF(MONTH, -32, ...` supposed to do? `-32` is the date `1899-12-01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for `dateadd()`:

> If the following are true:
>
> - datepart is month
> - the date month has more days than the return month
> - the date day does not exist in the return month
>
> Then, DATEADD returns the last day of the return month.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment:

> Why would you expect different values? Both `DATEDIFF(MONTH, -32, '20200229')-32` and `DATEDIFF(MONTH, -31, '20200229')-31` result in the value `1411`. The "date" `-1` is `1899-12-31`, and adding `1411` months (117 years 7 months) to that is `2017-07-31`.

Let's break it down:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, -32, '20200229')-32 AS DD1, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -31, '20200229')-31 AS DD2;
```

This returns the below:

```
DD1         DD2
----------- -----------
1411        1411
```

We can break the above into further steps too. For a `datetime`, the date `0` is `1900-01-01` and every full integer represents adding that many days to that date. `-32` as a date is therefore `1899-11-30`, and `-31` is `1899-12-01`. This gives us the 2 below expressions:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '18991130', '20200229') AS M1, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '18991201', '20200229') AS M2;
```

This returns the below:

```
M1          M2
----------- -----------
1443        1442
```

This make sense, as `DATEDIFF` counts the number of "ticks" between 2 dates. So for the expression `DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2019-12-31T23:59:59.9999999','2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000')` the value `1` is returned, even though only 1 millisecond has passed, because the value of the the year has changed (by 1).

The next part of that expression is `1443 - 32` and `1442 - 31` respectively. This is `1411` for both (basic maths).

You then have the "date" `-1`. You then add `1411` months (which is 117 years and 7 months) to the date `1899-12-31`, which (unsurprisingly) returns the same value: `2017-07-31`. `1899 + 117 = 2016`. `12 + 7 = 7` because we're working in months, so carry the `1` to the year: `2017-07-31`.